# How to install Tensorflow & keras in windows without cuda

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras

Can anyone guide me how to install keras and tensorflow without cuda in windows as i have only AMD graphics card..How to make it run in CPU?I have already installed python 3.6 and anaconda environment..

Answer (score 5):

You can find more information on this link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Follow the instructions of:
**2. Create a virtual environment (recommended)**, and select **Conda**.

For the following line of code: `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade <packageURL>`
you can use `https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.11.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` for `<packageURL>`

This is the TensorFlow Windows package, for Python 3.6 and CPU only (since you don't have a Nvidia GPU).